# Upload large files to Azure Media Services in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-core, upload, httpwebrequest, azure-media-services

I am trying to upload a .mp4 file, selected from the user's iOS or Android device, to my Azure Media Services account.

This code works for small files ( less than ~95MB):

```
public static async Task<string> UploadBlob(string blobContainerSasUri, string blobName, byte[] blobContent, string path)
    {
        string responseString;
        int contentLength = blobContent.Length;
        string queryString = (new Uri(blobContainerSasUri)).Query;
        string blobContainerUri = blobContainerSasUri.Split('?')[0];
        string requestUri = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}/{1}{2}", blobContainerUri, blobName, queryString);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
        request.ContentLength = contentLength;
        request.Timeout = Int32.MaxValue;
        request.KeepAlive = true;

        int bufferLength = 1048576; //upload 1MB at time, useful for a simple progress bar.

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.WriteTimeout = Int32.MaxValue;

        ProgressViewModel progressViewModel = App.Locator.GetProgressBar(App.Locator.MainViewModel.currentModuleItemId);
        MyVideosPage myVideosPage = App.Locator.GetVideosPage(App.Locator.MainViewModel.currentModuleItemId);

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        int nRead = 0;
        int currentPos = 0;
        while ((nRead = fileStream.Read(blobContent, currentPos, bufferLength)) > 0)
        {

            await requestStream.WriteAsync(blobContent, currentPos, nRead);
            currentPos += nRead;

        }
        fileStream.Close();
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse objHttpWebResponse = null;
        try
        {
            // this is where it fails for large files
            objHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = objHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            responseString = stream.ReadToEnd();                       
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (objHttpWebResponse != null)
                objHttpWebResponse.Close();
        }
        return responseString;
    }
```

An exception is thrown after this line is called:

```
(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

The exception message is "The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit."
The exception StatusCode is "RequestEntityTooLarge".

How can I upload large files? Is this a problem with HttpWebRequest, or Azure Media Services?

Comment: Why don't you use the Azure SDK which can handle most of this for you, writing CloudBlobBlocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Storage supports one [shot upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) (aka PutBlob API) up to 256MB if you are using the new REST API versions. But since you are not specifying the REST API version, you're defaulting to a very old version where the maximum supported size of one shot upload is 100MB.

Use `x-ms-version: 2018-03-28` header to be able to upload up to 256MB in one HTTP request.

If you have to deal with larger files, you will need to use block & commit upload. You will need to use [PutBlock API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) to stage blocks from the source file. Blocks can be up to 100MB each. Then you need to commit all the blocks using the [PutBlockList API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list). If you don't have to deal with this logic yourself, simply use the [Azure Storage SDK for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net) (supports Xamarin) and use the uploadFromFile method. It is simple, and resilient.